# efficient way in Spark scala to continuously merge input (fixed size) with RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, union

I wrote an small spark scala code to run some computer experiments with random inputs sampled in the design space. The logic of my computer experiment is defined in my mapper() function, but this is irrelevant to the question and we can treat it as a blackbox.

I have a stopping criteria for the sampling, which is when the maximum of all nearest neighbor distances of my sampling points is below a certain threshold d (any sampling point can find a neighbor no further than d).

Right now I am sampling every 500 points in each iteration, after that I union my new 500 RDD rows (variable "rdd") with my global RDD (variable "rddall"). Then I check the stopping criteria on "rddall".

I am not sure if using union() is the right way to do it. I am thinking about spark streaming. I know spark streaming can take input data by time increment. In my case the input is generated continuously with a block size of 500. How could I do this in spark streamming?

The reason I am doing the sampling iteratively is I need to check my stopping criteria and I can iteratively dump my results into my database such that writing results won't be performance bottleneck.

```
val sc = new SparkContext()       
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 

var rddall = sc.emptyRDD[Entry]
val numOfFeatures = 2
val partitions = 16
do {
    val columns = DenseMatrix.rand(500, numOfFeatures).toArray.grouped(500)
    val rows = columns.toSeq.transpose // Skip this if you want a column-major RDD.
    val vectors = rows.map(row => new DenseVector(row.toArray))
    val seedRdd = sc.parallelize(vectors, partitions)

    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val rdd = seedRdd.map(mapper)
    rddall = rddall.union(rdd)

    //check stopping criteria
    ...

    // write "rdd" and result to database
    ...
} while (!stop)
```